# Get latest value from firebase javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to build a table from my firebase database. However, in the last two columns, they show `[object][object]`. Those data were coming from the sensor reading.
I only want to show the latest value reading by the sensor through firebase in my table.
here is my database structure in firebase:

[image]

and here is the result in my html page:
[image]

and here is my javascript code:

```js
var config = {
    apiKey: "xxxxxxxxxx",
    authDomain: "xxxxxxxxx.firebaseio.com",
    databaseURL: "https://xxxxxx.firebaseio.com/",
    projectId: "xxxxxxx",
    storageBucket: "",
    messagingSenderId: "xxxxxx"
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);

//Add data to html table
var database = firebase.database().ref().child('locations');
database.on('value', function(snapshot){
    if(snapshot.exists()){
        var content = [];
        snapshot.forEach(function(data){
            var SerialNumber = data.val().SerialNumber;
            var Latitude= data.val().Latitude;
            var Longitude= data.val().Longitude;
            var FillLevel= data.val().FillLevel;
            var TrashDistance= data.val().TrashDistance;
            content += '<tr>';
            content += '<td>' + SerialNumber + '</td>'; //column1
            content += '<td>' + Latitude + '</td>';//column2
            content += '<td>' + Longitude + '</td>';//column3
            content += '<td>' + FillLevel + '</td>';//column4
            content += '<td>' + TrashDistance + '</td>';//column4
            content += '</tr>';
        });
        $('#ex-table').append(content);
    }
});
```

I do really appreciate any kinds of hints or a solution.
I was trying the whole day yesterday still no find any good answer by googling.

Comment: [object Object] is the result of converting an  object created by  `Object`  into a string. Console.log() `FillLevel` and `TrashDistance` to inspect their object values - they are not strings!

Comment: honestly I'm into the javascript less than a week. I'm not familiar with debugging with console.log(). Although, i'm trying to use it to show on developer console in chrome, still not giving what i am expecting...

Finally, I change the code on my Arduino.
Before was:
  // Push data to serial and Firebase
  if (distance >= 0 && distance <= 100){
      Firebase.pushInt("locations/0/FillLevel",distance_percent);
  }
  
and now become:
  if (distance >= 0 && distance <= 100){
      Firebase.setInt("locations/0/FillLevel",distance_percent);
  }

anyway, thanks for the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Since `TrashDistance` is a list, you'll need to loop over all children to find the last value:

```
var TrashDistance;
data.val().TrashDistance.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
  TrashDistance = childSnapshot.val();
})
console.log(TrashDistance);
```

Comment: Thanks Frank for your answer,

Does it mean I have to put on the nested loop?
I'm trying to add the code you provided below `var FillLevel= data.val().FillLevel;`
of my code to replace `var TrashDistance= data.val().TrashDistance;`

as a result, the value in my table were gone.

Comment: This code indeed needs to be inside your existing loop, since the data for `TrashDistance` is nested in the data of each location. The loop in my answer pretty much replaces the existing `var TrashDistance= data.val().TrashDistance;` line.